# Create .htaccess rewrite withou kill PHP session

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, session, url-rewriting

My website have this structure:

```
index.php
contact/
    index.php
news/
    index.php
admin/
    index.php
    [...]
vip/
    index.php
    [...]
```

My problem is that I don't need any redirections that contains my folders names (contact, news, vip, admin).

I want to do a solution where a person enter your username like www.site.com/your_user_name, and .htaccess redirects to function.php file to check if it's a valid username to show extra things in my site.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not entirely clear what your problem is, you should realize that your rewrite conditions only apply to the rewrite rule after it so your file reads as:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^vip/$ vip/index.php [QSA]


RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php [QSA]


RewriteRule ^([^-]+)/$ /initial/function.php?stat=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA]
```

You probably want to put your conditions before every rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^vip/$ vip/index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)/$ /initial/function.php?stat=$1 [QSA]
```

**Edit:** Based on your comments, it seems you just need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^\w+$ /function.php?user_name=$1 [QSA]    // if a username can only contain a-z, 0-9 and _
```

Comment: Jeroen, thinking better, my problem is that I don't need any redirections that contains my folders names (contact, news, vip, admin).

I want to do a solution where a person enter your username like www.site.com/your_user_name, and .htaccess redirects to function.php file to check if it's a valid username to show extra things in my site.

Comment: @Alan Gularte Then you only need one rule to rewrite all non-existing directories and file names to `function.php`.

Comment: yes, that's it, but I don't know if it's possible, or how to do it.

Comment: Man! You save my work!!! Tell me, this rule "^\w+$", how can I learn more about this rules? I don't know nothing about it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Alan Gularte It's just a regular expression, `\w` matches all "word" characters.

Comment: @Alan Gularte Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (the checkmark below the vote-count) if it works for you.

Comment: Hum... but how you just redirect the folders and files that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Alan Gularte The first two lines take care of that.

Comment: Hahaha, so simple! Thanks again, friend! =)